# How to getreceivedbyaddress() with the python-bitcoinlib?

Tags: json-rpc, python, python-bitcoinlib

I'm trying to use the [python-bitcoinlib](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib) in my bitcoin project. I now [understand how I can send a payment](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/24661/11136), but I can't find anything similar to the getreceivedbyaddress() command I normally used.

Isn't it present in the python-bitcoinlib, is there a workaround, or am I simply overlooking something? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not in there right now; look at the code in bitcoin/rpc.py and add it! Basically you just need to follow the same pattern as other RPC calls. When you're done send me a pull-req on github.

Comment: After I posted this question I indeed saw that the source code is not that difficult. Although I won't be doing it this or next week, I'll send you a pull request some time at github. Cheers! And thanks for actually creating this software! :)