# How to send user input data(Bitcoin address) from iPhone to server and then send Bitcoin back to user's Bitcoin address?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, python

Background I just got started yesterday learning Python and I'm currently building my first iPhone game.

What I'm trying to do is create a Bitcoin Pot Jar inside an iPhone app like Sarutobi:https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id932194840?mt=8

You can test out the game to see how it works. All the user does is paste their bitcoin address in an input field, somehow this data goes somewhere and then the user receives randomly small tip during gameplay. How do I create something like this? What code is used to make this work?

Comment: What is this?: client_pass = "dadfisasf#@$sdf3sfR"

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because this is a general programming question that is better suited for stackexchange.com.

Comment: I was sent here from stackexchange.com and now you're telling me to go back? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012008/how-to-send-bitcoin-address-from-iphone-to-server-and-then-send-bitcoin-back-to?noredirect=1#comment44412677_28012008

Comment: @cdecker While this is an incredibly broad question, its scope lies entirely within cryptocurrency. I've going to vote to leave open.

Comment: @bluebit You should get more familiar with Web Services. Bassically iPhone will send request for invoking method to Web Service that lies on your server. Server will create and broadcast the transaction. - Sorry for previously misleading link.

Comment: Ok, so this looks a lot harder than I expected. I'm totally new to code. Can someone breakdown a list of what I need to learn to accomplish my goal. Do I need my buy own Server or can I use an online service? I've been looking at resources on how to code, but there are so many languages, and everybody says something different, I need a good teacher.

Comment: @bluebit Please only ask one question per post.

Comment: I don't mean to be discouraging, but a project that involves transferring real money around (yes, Bitcoin is real money) is not a good idea for someone who's "totally new to code". You can very easily get all your money stolen, for one thing. I'd suggest starting with something much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I send a Bitcoin address from an iPhone to my server?

[Basic Python client socket example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297623/530160):

> Server side:
>
> ```
> import socket
>
> serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8089))
> serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections
>
> while True:
>     connection, address = serversocket.accept()
>     buf = connection.recv(64)
>     if len(buf) > 0:
>         print buf
>         break
> ```
>
> Client Side:
>
> ```
> import socket
>
> clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8089))
> clientsocket.send('hello')
> ```

#### How do I make a Bitcoin transaction using Python from my server?

[How to make a simple payment with the python-bitcoinlib?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24571/how-to-make-a-simple-payment-with-the-python-bitcoinlib)

> (Rewritten for brevity)
>
> [Run
>   bitcoind](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Linux_Quickstart),
>   install python-bitcoinlib, then run this code:
>
> ```
> from bitcoin.core import COIN, b2lx
> from bitcoin.base58 import CBitcoinAddress
> import bitcoin.wallet
> import bitcoin.rpc
>
> rpc = bitcoin.rpc.Proxy()
> addr = CBitcoinAddress('1JwSSubhmg6iPtRjtyqhUYYH7bZg3Lfy1T')
>
> txid = rpc.sendtoaddress(addr, 0.001 * COIN)
> print(b2lx(txid))
> ```